# I cannot seem to get past the "Who are you?"

Tags: system-installation, 10.10

While installing Ubuntu 10.10 on my newly partitioned drive - it stops at the login info screen and the "Forward" button won't activate and let me continue. I'm new to drive partitioning so I'm fairly sure I goofed up there. The drive partition was unformated, so I was letting the installation do the leg work.

Pardon me, utterly new to this. Any ideas? Or is there a guide I missed?

Answer (score 2):

If it's holding you at the login info screen, it must be that you are not filling in something on that page.  Are you filling in all five of the text fields: your name, your computer name, pick a username, choose a password and confirm your password?

If it helps, this video shows an entire successful installation: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=higI04jG6R8

Comment: dgman, video definitely helped! I was filling out everything, or at least, I think I was. I think my system may have been running slow? After the video I retried and it worked! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Your "user name" should be lower case it can contain only letters and numbers, and must start with a letter.

Comment: Wow i didnt know i needed my username to be a lower case O.O
Thx guys u helped me alot.